# how to refer the jquery function from the aspx page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the j-query function `test()` in (chart.js) another solution file which is added the reference of main projects. Now i want  to call the `test()` method from default.aspx page.

This is my code.

### chart.js

```
function test(){

//for Example
}
```

### default.aspx

```
<script>
test(); //call chart.js function
</script>
```

If i call the test method() from default.aspx page it is "undfined". how to call the j-query method which is located in another solution file but the same is added reference to the main project. Anyone could help on this..

Thanks,

Bharathi

Comment: I think you should use $(function(){test();})

Comment: Do you need to call the function manually? or just need to reference?

Answer (score 1):

you should put reference to tht perticular js file at starting of the page like below :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js" />
<script>
test(); //call chart.js function
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js">


$(document).ready(function()
   {
      test();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using a JS.page and that you are trying to call it with a script.

If you want to have your chart.js called into the default.aspx page do it like this.

```
<script src="assets/chart.js"></script>
```

place this in the head sections

Answer (score 0):

You have to add that js file (chart.js) before your script block, may be in head tags of page. like following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js" />
```

and Make sure your jQuery file is added even before it. so it should be like following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  test(); //call chart.js function
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **head section** of your aspx page add this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js" />//add reference of the chart.js file

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
          test(); //call chart.js function
    </script>
```